# Ternary operator on autoHeight for VirtualizedTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I am stuck on how to make a Virtualized Table using the Autosizer to shrink to the smallest possible height until a certain maximum threshold.

Is there a way to convert my autoHeight to use a conditional value?

```
autoheight={height<500}
```

Here is my render function:

```
 render(): ?React$Element<any> {
    const { columns, selectedItems, rulesList } = this.state;
    const { shouldRender, currentRule, sort } = this.props;

    if (!shouldRender) return <div />;

    return (
      <Grid columns={1} id="rulesTabContent">
        <Grid.Row style={NO_PADDING_BOTTOM}>
          <Grid.Column>
            <VirtualizedTable
              id="rulesTable"
              autoHeight={true}
              height={500}
              rowDef={rowDef => this.rowDef(rowDef, currentRule.id)}
              onRowDoubleClick={this.checkExpanded}
              columns={columns}
              sortVals={sort}
              setSort={this.updateSort}
              sortFn={this.sortFunc}
              getRowHeight={rowHeight}
              noRowsRenderer={this.noRowsRenderer}
              rowCount={rulesList.length}
              setSelectedItems={this.setSelectedItems}
              selectedItems={selectedItems}
              list={rulesList}
            />
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
```

Here is the render function of VirtualizedTable, which is used above:

```
 import {
  AutoSizer,
  Table,
  Column,
  SortIndicator,
  SortDirection
} from "react-virtualized";

.
.
.

render() {
   const {
      list,
      sortVals,
      onRowClick,
      onRowsRendered,
      noRowsRenderer,
      getRowHeight,
      columns,
      onRefresh,
      ...restOfProps
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <AutoSizer disableHeight>
        {({ width }) => (
          <Table
            headerClassName="virtualized-header"
            headerHeight={HEADER_HEIGHT}
            rowHeight={getRowHeight ? this._rowHeight : DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT}
            overscanRowCount={OVERSCAN}
            width={width}
            sort={this._sort}
            sortBy={sortVals.by}
            sortDirection={sortVals.direction}
            rowCount={list.size}
            noRowsRenderer={this._noRows}
            rowGetter={this._getRow}
            rowClassName={this._getRowClassName}
            rowRenderer={this._renderRow}
            onRowsRendered={this._onRowsRendered}
            onRowClick={this._onRowClick}
            {...restOfProps}
          >
            {Array.isArray(columns)
              ? columns
              : Object.keys(columns).map(key => columns[key])}
          </Table>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to debug without a demo, but maybe something like this?

```
return (
  <AutoSizer>
    {({ width, height }) => (
      <Table
        height={height}
        ...
```

-

```
<VirtualizedTable
  id="rulesTable"
  autoHeight={height < 500}
  height={Math.min(height, 500)}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was got me to my answer. I had to turn off autoHeight and then I used your height calculation and fed the AutoSizer the height as you wrote it. Also your user icon image is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

A little more info, are you looking for this?

```
style={{height: 'auto', max-height: '500px', overflow: 'scroll'})


this.state = {
autoHeight: {overflowX: 'hidden'},
}

{rulesList.length < 50 ? this.setState({autoHeight: {overFlowX: 'hidden'}}) : this.setState({autoHeight: overFlowX: 'scroll'}) }
```

From the Devs...

```
    style={{
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    overflowY: 'hidden'
  }}
```

So you would need to add a style that looks something like this.

```
style={this.state.autoHeight}
```

Heres a closed issue on the topic 
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/488

Comment: I am not sure, I am new to react virtualized and I inherited this table. I just want the table size to be able to fit-to-size when the table is shorter than 500 pixels. After 500 pixels it should just scroll.

Comment: I see, what Table are you using? what package?

Comment: I will update my post, I am using "react-virtualized" in the VirtualizedTable. Just in case it is not clear, the table I list first uses the table beneath it.

Comment: I do not understand. There is no problem with scroll bars. My issue is that when I say have two rows, the table height is 500 pixels, just the same as when I have 200 rows. This is a problem when I have few rows because elements appearing beneath my table are hard to find and placed way below the table. Does this make sense? I may have done a poor job explaining above.

Comment: Yea, now I'm confused because your first comment mentioned scrolling when it got too big. I think you need to use my above example and have some styling like...
    style={{height: 'auto', max-height: '500px', overflow: 'scroll'})
Then, it will grow up to 500px, and after that the overflow will scroll..

Comment: Sorry about that, my issue is that when the table is shorter than 500px in terms of rows, the table still takes up 500px. I was initially surprised to not see a MaxHeight that could be used with autoHeight in react-virtualized.

Comment: I see I will delete my answer, I am mistaken. I found this site... which I'm assuming you already looked at? You can view source code for all their examples. Maybe it will help you https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/?component=AutoSizer#/components/List